# Pandas Dataframe Comparison and Copying

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Below I have two dataframes, the first being dataframe det and the second being orig. I need to compare `det['Detection']` with `orig['Date/Time']`. Once the values are found during the comparion, I need to copy values from `orig` and `det` to some final dataframe (`final`). The format that I need the final dataframe in is `det['Date/Time'] orig['Lat'] orig['Lon'] orig['Dep'] det['Mag']`  I hope that my formatting is adequate for folks. I was not sure how to handle the dataframes so I just placed them in tables. Some additional information that probably won't matter is that `det` is 3385 rows by 3 columns and `orig` is 818 rows by 9 columns.

`det`:

| Date/Time | Mag | Detection |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2008/12/27T01:06:56.37 | 0.280 | 2008/12/27T13:50:07.00 |
| 2008/12/27T01:17:39.39 | 0.485 | 2008/12/27T01:17:39.00 |
| 2008/12/27T01:33:23.00 | -0.080 | 2008/12/27T01:17:39.00 |

`orig`:

| Date/Time | Lat | Lon | Dep | Ml | Mc | N | Dmin | ehz |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2008/12/27T01:17:39.00 | 44.5112 | -110.3742 | 5.07 | -9.99 | 0.51 | 5 | 6 | 3.2 |
| 2008/12/27T04:33:30.00 | 44.4985 | -110.3750 | 4.24 | -9.99 | 1.63 | 9 | 8 | 0.9 |
| 2008/12/27T05:38:22.00 | 44.4912 | -110.3743 | 4.73 | -9.99 | 0.37 | 8 | 8 | 0.8 |

`final`:

| det['Date/Time'] | orig['Lat'] | orig['Lon'] | orig['Dep'] | det['Mag'] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Comment: seems like you wanna use inner merge. Check - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: I agree with @Nk03 something like `final = det.merge(orig[['Date/Time', 'Lat', 'Lon']], on='Date/Time')` see also [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53645882/15497888)

Comment: I had almost solved it using the inner merge method but it was missing a lot of the rows. I appreciate the input! @Don'tAccept was able to solve this problem. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge the two dataframes, since you want to use `Detection` column from the first data frame and `Date/Time` column from the second dataframe, you can just rename the column of second dataframe while merging since the column name already exits in the first dataframe:

```py
det.merge(org.rename(columns={'Date/Time': 'Detection'}))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
                Date/Time    Mag               Detection      Lat       Lon   Dep    Ml    Mc  N  Dmin  ehz
0  2008/12/27T01:17:39.39  0.485  2008/12/27T01:17:39.00  44.5112 -110.3742  5.07 -9.99  0.51  5     6  3.2
1  2008/12/27T01:33:23.00 -0.080  2008/12/27T01:17:39.00  44.5112 -110.3742  5.07 -9.99  0.51  5     6  3.2
```

You can then select the columns you want.